# Wireless Presentation System does not show my C# WinForm Application

Tags: c#, winforms, wireless, projector, borderless

I have written a border-less WinForm application in C#.

On some laptops, when they connect to a Wireless Presentation System (WPS Projector), Although the display is set on "duplicate", the main form of my application becomes hidden.

It is visible on the laptop but invisible on wireless projector. But it is ok when we use a VGA cable to connect to it.

I am not able to use the WPS for a long time to try and find what is wrong. Has anyone had a same problem? I need to save time.

**Edit:**

There was an option inside the menu of WPS named **"Advanced Screen Capture"**, when checked, aero got enabled and my application became visible. so the critical problem is fixed but the question remains that why **"Simple Screen Capture"** aims my application?

To figure out the question, I tested these cases:

1. enabled the Border (using BorderStyle property)
2. enabled the ControlBox (using properties)
3. removed the drop shadow feature (using wmproc)
4. added accessibility role (using properties)

The simple capturing still aims my application, however, newly created WinForm .net application works fine.

Comment: Might have something to do with DirectX. You could try to switch off hardware rendering.

Comment: @rene you mean .net is related to DirectX? or WPS is the one related?

Comment: Not sure. From a quick search I see that some applications experience the problems you see with specific settings. So it could be a combination of both, DirectX being used, in combination with the device driver for the wireless projector

Comment: Go to Visual Studio, try `File -> New Project -> WPF Application` and see if the resulting WPF window works ok. If it does, then forget winforms and use relevant technology. If it doesn't then troubleshoot further.

Comment: You might get someone who has experienced this problem before and can recall the solution off the top of your head. But you are usually not that lucky. You'd *significantly* increase your chances of getting a good answer if you could post the code for a sample app that reproduces the problem. Use the standard debugging techniques: create a copy of your application and rip out code until the bug goes away. Whatever the last thing you removed, that was the problem. (And ignore HighCore, he's just shilling for WPF, which will require you to rewrite the app and still won't solve your problem.)

Comment: @CodyGray Yeah this is called revise engineering, or revise troubleshooting. I really like it, But it takes so much time that i don't have. Using WPS is not allowed for anyone at anytime in our company. (I agree with you about HighCore, we had bad arguments before)